# Getter and Setter in Array

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I need help for unexpected output from my code below.
I was create a class I called "Student" and mainclass I called "MainStudent", I don't have wrong code when I try make Student object to Array and input data using setter, but when I run my code then the output is says like this one:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

I'm using NetBeans for write my java code.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class MainStudent {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a,b;
        int c;
        Student[] std = new Student[3];
        for(int i=0; i<std.length; i++){
            a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Student Name");
            b = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Student Address");
            c = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Student Phone Number"));
            std[i].setName(a);
            std[i].setAddress(b);
            std[i].setPhone_number(c);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<std.length; i++){
            System.out.println(std[i].getName());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to instantiate your array with Students.

At the top of your loop, add:

```
std[i] = new Student();
```

The line:

```
Student[] std = new Student[3];
```

Only creates a data structure, capable of holding exactly three students.  The indexes inside the array do not actually contain anything, and in-fact contain a null, which is why you are getting a null pointer.  You are saying "Structure std, get me the thing in index i", and it promptly hands you a null value because you've never put anything into index i.

Answer (score 1):

Initializing an array just creates an array of `null`s with the given size - you still need to initialize each element individually. E.g.:

```
Student[] std = new Student[3];
for(int i=0; i<std.length; i++){
    a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Student Name");
    b = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Student Address");
    c = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Student Phone Number"));
    std[i] = new Student(); // Create the object first
    std[i].setName(a);
    std[i].setAddress(b);
    std[i].setPhone_number(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use lists instead arrays:

```
List<Student> std = new ArrayList<Student>();
for(int i=0; i<std.length; i++){
    Student _tmpStudent = new Student();
    a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Student Name");
    b = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Student Address");
    c = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Student Phone Number"));
    _tmpStudent.setName(a);
    _tmpStudent.setAddress(b);
    _tmpStudent.setPhone_number(c);
    std.add(_tmpStudent);
}
```

In your case you getting error, because std[i] object is not exists, put `std[i] = new Student()` after for.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code is correct for all of your Student class, you just need to initialize a student object for each iteration of your for loop that contains the dialog boxes.

Inserting

```
std[i] = new Student();
```

as the first line in your for loop will probably fix your problem, because it will create a student object whose values it can set. Without initializing a Student object, setX() tries to set the default values of std: a null object.

Revisit your constructors and determine where to place it. Just make sure you construct the object before passing it a method.